# How to get the coordinate of the 3rd side of a triangle if you know the length of all sides and the coordinate of other two sides

Tags: triangles

I have seen similar questions before but there most of the part is that in general they start from origin.But here is my question.

Just in a plane you have to construct triangle at some random place.The values of (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are known and the length of the 3 sides of the triangle is given. How to find a general formula which would give the value of x3 and y3 as such.

I tried using distance formula in my notes which is basically squared root of the difference between x and y,but it got all messy.

The other Herons formula but everything is kind of messed up my head now

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Do you realize that there are two possibilities for the third point?  How would you solve the problem with a pair of compasses?

Comment: If you know how to do it when when of the vertices is at the origin, then you can translate all your vertices by $(-x_1,-y_1)$ so your first vertex is now at the origin, solve the problem, then translate back by $(x_1,y_1)$.